# Conflicting Change in Momentum Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

This is a peculiar question taken from the IBDP question bank (and hence also from an official exam). It is from the November 2016 SL paper 1.

[image: Question 8 from IBDP physics SL November 2016 paper 1]

The question asks for "the **change in the magnitude of the momentum** of the ball." This is equal to the final magnitude of momentum minus the initial magnitude of momentum.

$$\Delta |\vec{p}|=|\vec{p}|_{\mathrm{f}}-|\vec{p}|_{\mathrm{i}}=|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}|-|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|$$

I would like to note that the question does **not** ask for the magnitude of the change in the momentum of the ball as that is a **different** quantity. I did make the mistake of $|a-b|=|a|-|b|$ but that is **not** valid (triangle inequality).

When I first saw the question it also was obvious to me that the change is **zero**. It's clear that $|\vec{p}|=m|\vec{v}|$ which, in this case, means $|\vec{p}|=mv$. $m$ and $v$ remain constant hence the change in the magnitude is zero.

The length of the scaled vector arrow representing the momenta is the same for before and after... so obviously there is no change? Yet for some reason the answer the IB gives is A from the exam and B from the question bank (for the exact same question), not even coinciding...

I believe there were two odd ways of thinking in making A/B the answer instead of D. First, the 'IB physics' way to approach the problem: It is clear that the final $v_y$ equals the initial $v_y$ (vertical component of velocity), so there is no change, but $v_{x\mathrm{i}}=-v_{x\textrm{f}}$. Hence $\Delta|\vec{p}|=m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}}-(m\cdot-v_{x\mathrm{f}})=2m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}}$. Now comes the second issue (and why I assume the answers differ): the wording of the question does not match the diagram. It says "at an angle of $\theta$ **to the wall**" but the diagram shows an angle $\theta$ to the normal. If we use the diagram, we come to the IB result of $\Delta|\vec{p}|=2mv\cos\theta$, and we get $\sin$ if we consider the angle $\theta$ "to the wall."

I however cannot follow this logic with simply considering 1 component, so you could also formulate the above using the **incorrect** assumption that $|a-b|=|a|-|b|$:
\begin{align*}
    \Delta |\vec{p}|&=|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}|-|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|\\
    &= |\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}-\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|\\
    &= |m\vec{v}_{\mathrm{f}}-m\vec{v}_{\mathrm{i}}|\\
    &= \left| \begin{pmatrix} m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}}\\m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}} \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} m\cdot -v_{x\mathrm{f}}\\m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}} \end{pmatrix}\right|\\
    &=\left|\begin{pmatrix} 2m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}}\\0 \end{pmatrix}\right|\\
    &= \sqrt{(2m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}})^2}\\
    &= \sqrt{(-2mv\cos\theta)^2}\\
    &= 2mv\cos\theta.
\end{align*}

You can also do the above graphically by taking the final and initial momenta vector arrows and subtracting them (which gives you a vector arrow whose length is twice the horizontal component of velocity), but, **again**, this gives the result $|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}-\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|$ which is **NOT** what we are looking for!

I want to stress however that this 'property' of magnitudes is not true. Instead, $|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$ (triangle inequality).

Here is the examiner report from the question bank (I *hope* this isn't a real examiner report...)

> Momentum is a vector quantity so the angle and the direction are both relevant to the answer. Hence C and D can be eliminated. If $\theta=90°$, then the ball is just rolling down the wall and there is no change in momentum. Hence B is correct ($\cos 90°=0$).

This still baffles me. It is **obvious** that the **magnitude of momentum** does NOT change as neither the mass nor the speed of the ball change. **IF** the question had asked "What is the magnitude of the change of the momentum of the ball?" this response would be correct, but that is not what is asked. The following working goes beyond the scope of IB physics (understanding that the magnitude does not change is all that is required to answer this question), but it does make it rigorous in my eyes:

\begin{align*}
    \Delta |\vec{p}|&=|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}|-|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|\quad(\neq|\vec{p}_{\mathrm{f}}-\vec{p}_{\mathrm{i}}|)\\
    &= \left | \begin{pmatrix} m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}} \\ m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}} \end{pmatrix} \right|-\left| \begin{pmatrix} m\cdot -v_{x\mathrm{f}}\\ m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}} \end{pmatrix} \right|\\
    &= \sqrt{(m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}})^2+(m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}})^2}-\sqrt{(-m\cdot v_{x\mathrm{f}})^2+(m\cdot v_{y\mathrm{f}})^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{m^2(v_{x\mathrm{f}}{}^2+v_{y\mathrm{f}}{}^2)}-\sqrt{m^2(v_{x\mathrm{f}}{}^2+v_{y\mathrm{f}}{}^2)} \\
    &= 0.
\end{align*}

The triangle inequality still holds though. As the examiner reported (although they incorrectly referred to the vector nature of momentum even though this question is only concerned with magnitude), when $\theta=90°$ the incorrect answer (which is equivalent to $|a-b|$) yields $0$, and it will never be less than $0$ as $90°$ is the maximum angle for which this question makes sense, so $|a-b|\geq|a|-|b|$ (greater than or equal to $0$).

I find it difficult to believe that the IB truly marked this question incorrectly for everyone, but I can't come up with any alternative explanation. Am I making some silly mistake?

Comment: I might be sleep deprived but zero seems to be the obvious and correct answer. The velocity is the same, and the mass does not change either; the direction is irrelevant as we are only concerned with the magnitude.

Comment: It appears to be very obvious to me, too. Yet the IB says the official answer is either A or B (they can't even agree on that). I'd have to consult with them, because it would be a serious issue if people lost marks on this kind of question... It could be that the online resources are not up-to-date, that is most likely I guess?

Comment: I think you might have missed something in your derivation but got lucky. $$\sqrt(2mv_{xf})^2 = |2mv_{xf}|$$ $$2mv_{xf} = -2m|\vec{v}|cos(\theta)$$ it is negative because the direction is opposite $\hat i$ then the abs value removes this negative.

Comment: Yup, forgot to include that detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was poorly constructed and did not go through sufficient proof-reading and review.

If the answer is A or B, then the question should have asked for "the magnitude of the change in momentum," not "the change in the magnitude of the momentum."

If the answer is A, $2mv\sin\theta$, then the angles are labeled wrongly in the diagram.

If the answer is B, $2mv\cos\theta$, then the wording "an angle of $\theta$ to the wall" is incorrect and should be changed to "an angle of $\theta$ to the normal of the wall."

As written, the most correct answer is D. This question should be reported to the body that wrote the exam so that it can be corrected or removed.

Comment: I will purchase the really official marking scheme and see if they possibly corrected the mistake or removed the question. If not, I will get in touch with the board

Answer (score 0):

You are correct I think.

The change in magnitude of the momentum, to me, would mean

$|p_{2}|-|p_{1}| = 0$

The magnitude of the change in momentum would be:

$| p_{2}  - p_{1}| = 2mv cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

You say (after correction by another person answering) the magnitude of the change in momentum is

$|\Delta \vec{p}| = |\vec{p}_f| - |\vec{p}_i|$

That's not correct.  What is actually correct is

$|\Delta \vec{p}| = |\vec{p}_f - \vec{p}_i| \neq |\vec{p}_f| - |\vec{p}_i|$

Remember, the change in momentum is itself a vector.  Draw the vector subtraction triangle to see it.

[image]

The size of that red arrow is what you are looking for.  So, a little trig. carried out on that triangle ought to give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Be careful with the notation. The question explicitly asks for the **change in the magnitude of the momentum**. What you have just found is the magnitude of the change in the momentum which, as you noted, is a different quantity. I believe it is clear we are looking for $\Delta|\vec{p}|$, **NOT** $|\Delta\vec{p}|$.